# How to show the worked years in SQL with select?

Tags: sql, oracle

```
SELECT LAST_NAME
      ,DEPARTMENT_ID
      ,ROUND(MONTHS_BETWEEN (SYSDATE, hire_date)) MONTHS_WORKED
FROM   EMPLOYEES 
WHERE DEPARTMENT_ID = 90
ORDER BY MONTHS_WORKED;
```

This select is for "hr" schema in Oracle. 
The question is how to make it to show the years and months worked?

Comment: (1) There is no need to YELL.  (2) Provide sample data, desired results, and what *you* mean by "worked years".

Comment: I have made it work to show the months but i need "years and months"

Comment: the code as its now shows just the months. exaple: months_worked 172
I want to be 14 years 4 months

Answer (score 0):

We could build on your current attempt with `months_between`. We can divide the result by 12 to get the number of years; the modulo (ie the remainder) represents the number of months:

```
select 
    last_name,
    department_id, 
    floor(months_between(sysdate, hire_date)/12) years_worked,
    floor(mod(months_between(sysdate, hire_date), 12)) months_worked
from employees 
where department_id = 90
order by years_worked, months_worked;
```